# FileOutputStream in dart flutter

Tags: java, flutter, file, dart

what's the equivalent fileoutputstream of java in dart?
**Java code**

```
file = new FileOutputStream(logFile, true);
byte[] input = "String".getBytes();
file.write(input);
```

java file output

> **String**

Ive tried this in dart
**Dart code**

```
var file = File(logFile!.path).openWrite();
List input = "String".codeUnits;
file.write(input);
```

> **[String]**

and every time I open the file again to append "String2" and "String3" to it, the output will be

> **[String][String2][String3]**

as oppose to java's output

> **StringString3String3**

to sum it up, is there a way to fix/workaround this?
why each array bytes written in dart will be a new array instead of append into an existing one?

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with the code you've shown.  Please post a reproducible example.  Using `File(path).openWrite(mode: FileMode.append).write("String")` writes `String` to the file, not `[String]`.  It sounds like you're accidentally calling `write()` on a `List<String>`.

Comment: i think i may have left an important detail, i did not write a string, i wrote a string in array bytes.

Comment: That isn't what your example shows.  Please provide code that actually reproduces the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Either your example is still bogus, or you're lying about what the output is.  If you actually did `file.write("String".codeUnits);`, your file would end up with `[83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]`.

Comment: It's also now unclear what actual problem you're trying to solve.  If you want `StringString3String3` written to the file, your original code already did that.  There's no reason for you to use `.codeUnits`.  Or, if you are starting from a list of UTF-16 code units, you can create `String`s from them with [`String.fromCharCodes`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/String.fromCharCodes.html).

Comment: i cant post the actual code as it is signed under NDA, so yes, i have to lie in this case,
and it is my fault i forgot to include the important part, anyway, i solved it with BytesBuilder() and ByteData byteData = ByteData.sublistView(Uint8List.fromList(input)), combined with writeAsBytes()

thanks for spending time taking a look into it anyway.

Comment: I don't expect you to copy and paste confidential code.  However, when you ask questions, I do expect you to write a minimal version that actually demonstrates the problem you're asking about.  Doing so in this case should have been trivial.  Otherwise you're wasting everybody's time.

Comment: BTW, using `writeAsBytes` with `codeUnits` won't do what you want if your strings have non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using `File.writeAsString()` and using FileMode.append.
Picking up your example, this would be:

```
var file = File(logFile!.path);
file.writeAsString("String", mode: FileMode.append);
```

Comment: thanks for this i found writeAsBytes for my usage.

Answer (score -1):

did you try writeAsString() ?

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  final filename = 'file.txt';
  var file = await File(filename).writeAsString('some content');
  // Do something with the file.
}
```